# Bundle Install fails due to problems with 'pg (>= 0) ruby` on OSX Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, rubygems, pg

**Updated with solution at end of question**

I've been going round and round in circles trying to resolve issues with my pg gem & rails server. I've outlined the endless loop that I've found myself in. Can you please provide some guidance?

**When I try starting my rails server, I get the following error message:**

```
Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

**After this, I run `bundle install` and get the following message:**

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/3l/gxc7bb4x0nb6b7n7039jl49r0000gn/T/bundler20170112-83505-1jpf7s0pg-0.19.0/gems/pg-0.19.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/3l/gxc7bb4x0nb6b7n7039jl49r0000gn/T/bundler20170112-83505-1jpf7s0pg-0.19.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.19.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**Next I run, `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'` and get this error message:**

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

**I then try to run `sudo gem install pg -v '0.19.0'` and get this error message:**

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.19.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

**If it helps, I've also run `rbenv versions` which shows:**

```
  system
* 2.1.0 (set by /Users/{user}/.rbenv/version)
```

**I also tried completely uninstalling postgres and then re-installing using this guide: https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/**

**Where do I go from here?**

Comment: Do you have the postgresql (either server or client ) installed on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I ran `brew update` and `brew install postgresql` immediately prior to this. I'll update the post.

Comment: `ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' gem install pg` does that make a difference?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`

Comment: Well that doesn't seem like you are running under rbenv as it is trying to install on the system ruby so you might have multiple issues.

Comment: @Doon - thanks. I was thinking potentially the same thing. I just ran `echo $PATH` and the results were: `/Users/{user}/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`. I'm going to try uninstalling & re-installing rbenv and see if that sorts it out

Answer (score 0):

Try to install postgresql

`brew install postgresql`

if it does not work update the brew by

`brew update`

and try it again

#### Edited.

Another solution is to install xcode command line tools

`xcode-select --install`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Immediately prior to this problem, I followed this tutorial: https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/ and can confirm that `lunchy start postgres` works. I'll udpate the post.

Comment: Thanks for the updated solution: xcode command line tools are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I ended up uninstalling/reinstalling absolutely everything. Here are all the things I rebuilt from scratch:

1. Uninstall/Reinstall PostgreSQL
2. Updated path var so that anaconda was at the end
3. Reinstall rbenv
4. Uninstall/Reinstall Ruby 2.1.0
5. Re-run gem install bundle
6. Re-run bundle install
7. Re-run rake db:setup and rake db:migrate

And then things were *finally* squared away :)